# Removing a View from parent vs hiding it

Tags: android

In android if I remove a view from its parent vs hide a child view (GONE + Invisible) in a parent. I understand the hidden view will still be in memory but Speaking of the physical appearance of the parent view would it make any difference ? and if the answer is no difference does that mean the entire layout of the child view is essentially not present in the parent when I hide it ?

Comment: define *hiding*, do you mean `GONE` or `INVISIBLE`

Comment: Well I want to understand both in comparison with removing it

Answer (score 5):

**First of GONE & INVISIBLE are two different things.**

When you change visibility using GONE

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

But on the other side, when you change visibility using INVISIBLE

> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

***So the real question is REMOVE vs GONE***

#### REMOVE

When you remove a view, it's removed from the layout's hierarchy. Which means it's no longer a child of it's parent. So this view can now be used in any other ViewGroup.

#### GONE

When you change the visibility to GONE, it's made invisible and the space allotted is removed, but it's still a child of it's parent. And because of that, it cannot be used in any other ViewGroup since a child can have only one parent.

**When to use REMOVE**

To me, you have to REMOVE the view, if you are either moving the View to another ViewGroup, or when you want to hide it permanently.

**When to use GONE**

When you want to toggle visibility, along with the space allotted for it in the parent View. After visibility is set to GONE, user can't distinguish whether there was a View in the first place.

**When to use INVISIBLE**

Similarly to GONE, when you want to toggle visibility, but you don't want to remove the space allotted for it in the parent View. So the UI will look like something is hidden.

Comment: @4k3RI want to add Images daynamically to my linearlayout that i have done. later I remove some of images from layout. then I want to restore it at its own position from where I have removed. means I want to add images without removing child's parent can you please hlep me ?